# Is a Masters Degree mandatory to gain entrance to a PhD in US

Tags: phd, application, united-states

I have been working as a Research Assistant in a university for 2 years under the supervision of a supervisor who has a doctoral degree.

I have fair knowledge about research and a first class for my Bachelors Degree. I wish to apply for a PhD in United States.

Is it possible to secure a PhD opportunity without a Masters Degree?

Comment: Did you do a four-year or a three-year bachelor?

Comment: No. I did a three year Bachelor. Would that be a problem? I have several publications and a journal I am expecting to publish next year. But I am starting to apply before the latter publications will be published.

Comment: I recall that there was once the question on this webpage whether applicants from Germany need a Masters before applying to a US PhD program - if I recall correctly, the answer was that in many situations, the answer is actually yes because many US universities require 4 years of "undergraduate" study before starting PhD studies, meaning that a Masters is rquired except if a 4 years Bachelor degree has been obtained.

Comment: Thats sad. I mean I have experience as a RA for 2 years with publications. Still, they want that extra one year. What do you think is the reason for this? It doesnt make sence.

Comment: Can't give a blanket answer. Even if regulations say it can't be done, I'm sure they will make an exception for a stellar applicant, or waive the requirement for previous research experience/publication record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in a rough manner...

There are a multitude of Ph.D. programs, presented by US universities, within which the M.Sc. degree would not be as a mandatory factor for entrance the target program.

As a matter of fact, direct transition from B.Sc. (first-class or 4-year one) to Ph.D. would be a research plan for the future action within the academia, where one often seeks a M.Sc. degree for the participation within the industry.

All in all, you better check the admission requirements of the target programs, by case, to realize the necessity...

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to secure a PhD opportunity without a Masters Degree?

Yes. At my institution this is the most frequent applicant profile in fact.

Answer (score 1):

At my university, you're at a disadvantage when you apply to a PhD program when you already have a masters. So essentially, yes it's possible and more than likely preferable!

Comment: May I please know your university? I would love to see if my field ( Embedded Systems, Electronics) exist there. Thank you very much.

Comment: University of Virginia. I don't know much of the Engineering School, so I honestly don't know if they have this or not. I would also check into funding opportunities to make sure they cover the specific degree.

Comment: I truly appreciate your feedback very much @user46666.